# Wikitude - Can't load architect world

Tags: ios, cordova, wikitude

I'm using wikitude plugin and phonegap for my augmented reality mobile app (iOS) project. My problem is, I cant load architect world even my relative path is correct. It shows nothing on my screen.

Screenshot
[image]

My code in index.js

```
loadARchitectWorld: function(sample) {

        if (app.isDeviceSupported) {

                WikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld("www/world/5_BrowsingPois_3_LimitingRange/index.html");

            // if you want to listen to document.location = architectsdk://yourhost?param1=foo&param2=bar simply set the onUrlInvoceCallback
            WikitudePlugin.setOnUrlInvokeCallback( app.onClickInARchitectWorld );
        }
    },
```

My folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Wikitude PhoneGap [sample application](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples)? It loads worlds using relative paths.
You can also set onError callbacks for both, the `isDeviceSupported` and `loadARchitectWorld` (There are variables on the WikitudePlugin where you can set a custom callback function for world loading errors).